# how to select svg element by variable name for id

Tags: d3.js

How do I create an SVG, append a TEXT, then back under SVG append a G which will host some CIRCLEs? I'm creating several of these constructions, so just referring to .select('svg') does not work as all the G elements stack to the first SVG in targetDIV, rather than the appropriate one. Thanks!
- Corbin Supak

```
//done in a loop several times...
svg = d3.select(targetDIV)
                        .append('svg')
                        .attr('id', targetSVG)
                        .attr('height', svgHeight)
                        .append('text')
                        .attr("transform", "translate(0,"+markSize+")")
                        .text(status)
                        .style("font-size",markSize+"px")
                        ;
                    g = d3.select(targetSVG)
                        .append('g')
                        .attr("transform", "translate("+markSize/2+", "+markSize/2+")");
                        ;
                    g.selectAll("circle")
                        .data(statusAlerts)
                        .enter()
                        .append("circle")
                        .attr("cx", function(d,i) {
                            return (i*markSize) + markSize/2 + 50;//50 is to give room for text label
                            })
                        .attr("cy", 0)
                        .attr("r", markSize/2)
                        .attr("fill", alertColor)
                        ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a minimal skeleton...

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
...;

var g = svg.select("g").append("g")
...;

svg.append("text")
...;

g.append("circle")
...;
```

Comment: sorry for the hastiness...`var g = svg.append("g")`